# wordpress custom_meta ordering of timestamps

Tags: mysql, wordpress, sorting

So I have a wp meta query that is handling the searching of events which have a start timestamp, and an end timestamp, I want to return all results within the two dates a user picks in the search. This part is working fine as of now.

However, I want to sort the results by the start timestamp, so the most recent events show up first.

```
$args = array(
    's' => $_GET['k'],
    'post_type' => 'event',
    'posts_per_page' => '-1',
    'post_status' => array( 'private','publish' ),

    'meta_key' =>'_start_ts',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'asc',

    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key' => '_end_ts',
            'value' => array(strtotime($_GET['d1']),strtotime($_GET['d2'])),
            'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
            'type' => 'NUMERIC'
        ),
        array(
            'key' => '_start_ts',
            'value' => array(strtotime($_GET['d1']),strtotime($_GET['d2'])),
            'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
            'type' => 'NUMERIC'
        )
    )
);
```

If I seach for all events in the month of april, we get the following timestamp ordering:

1397865600,
1398211200,
1398384000,
1397520000,
1398297600

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same kind of events in my database. Used your args and the query executes beautifully. The one difference is that my dates come from the database as yyyymmdd values. I'm using Advanced Custom Fields plugin which saves in this format.

Here's my adapted code

```
$args = array(
    's' => 'old',
    'post_type' => 'event',
    'posts_per_page' => '-1',
    'post_status' => array( 'private','publish' ),

    'meta_key' =>'start_date',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'asc',

    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key' => 'end_date',
            'value' => array(strtotime('20130101'),strtotime('20140101')),
            'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
            'type' => 'NUMERIC'
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'start_date',
            'value' => array(strtotime('20130101'),strtotime('20140101')),
            'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
            'type' => 'NUMERIC'
        )
    )
);
$search = new WP_Query($args);

if ( $search->have_posts() ):

    setlocale(LC_ALL, 'nl_NL.UTF-8');

    while ( $search->have_posts() ) : $search->the_post();

        $start_date = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'start_date', true);
        $end_date = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'end_date', true);
        $start = strftime( '%A %e %B %Y', strtotime( $start_date ) );
        $end = strftime( '%A %e %B %Y', strtotime( $end_date ) );


        echo "$start ($start_date) - $end ($end_date) <br />";

    endwhile;
endif;
```

And here's the result

```
zaterdag 3 mei 2014 (20140503) - zaterdag 3 mei 2014 (20140503) 
zondag 4 mei 2014 (20140504) - zondag 4 mei 2014 (20140504) 
zondag 4 mei 2014 (20140504) - zondag 4 mei 2014 (20140504) 
zondag 11 mei 2014 (20140511) - zondag 11 mei 2014 (20140511) 
vrijdag 16 mei 2014 (20140516) - zondag 18 mei 2014 (20140518) 
zaterdag 17 mei 2014 (20140517) - zaterdag 17 mei 2014 (20140517) 
zondag 18 mei 2014 (20140518) - zondag 18 mei 2014 (20140518) 
zondag 1 juni 2014 (20140601) - zondag 1 juni 2014 (20140601) 
zondag 1 juni 2014 (20140601) - zondag 1 juni 2014 (20140601) 
zondag 15 juni 2014 (20140615) - zondag 15 juni 2014 (20140615) 
donderdag 26 juni 2014 (20140626) - donderdag 26 juni 2014 (20140626) 
zondag 29 juni 2014 (20140629) - zondag 29 juni 2014 (20140629) 
zaterdag 5 juli 2014 (20140705) - zondag 6 juli 2014 (20140706) 
zondag 6 juli 2014 (20140706) - zondag 6 juli 2014 (20140706) 
zondag 6 juli 2014 (20140706) - zondag 6 juli 2014 (20140706) 
zondag 10 augustus 2014 (20140810) - zondag 10 augustus 2014 (20140810) 
zondag 17 augustus 2014 (20140817) - zondag 17 augustus 2014 (20140817) 
zondag 7 september 2014 (20140907) - zondag 7 september 2014 (20140907) 
zaterdag 13 september 2014 (20140913) - zaterdag 13 september 2014 (20140913) 
zondag 14 september 2014 (20140914) - zondag 14 september 2014 (20140914) 
zondag 28 september 2014 (20140928) - zondag 28 september 2014 (20140928) 
zondag 5 oktober 2014 (20141005) - zondag 5 oktober 2014 (20141005)
```